# How to fix Angular Http Post Request sending more than once?

Tags: angular, http, post

I'm debugging my APIService's Post method which SOMETIMES sends twice. This is hard to debug because it only happens sometimes on Post requests. When a user initiates a Create action, for example, when creating a new user, sometimes the server will respond saying "The user already exists!" when I know for a fact it does not exist.

Looking at server logs immediately following the problem reveals that for that call, it was sent twice. The first request successfully creates the user and the second call see's that the user already exists from the previous request. So the server says, that user already exists! These requests happen one after the other but not always. The server doesn't always get 2 requests either. Sometimes it works as expected and then every once in a while it will Post twice...

I tried putting a console.log in the ApiService Post method and it shows up once even when the double Post occurs. I'm baffled...

CreateUser Action that calls Post method in ApiService:

```
  @Action(CreateUser)
  createUser(sc: StateContext<AdminTreeStateModel>, action: any) {
    console.log("Create User Action!");
    let form = action.payload,
        params = {
          kouser: {
            username: form.username,
            fullName: form.fullName,
            email: form.email,
            role: form.role,
            state: form.state,
            authType: form.authType
          }
        };
    if (form.authType === 'local')
      params.kouser['password'] = form.password;
    else if (form.authType === 'external')
      delete params.kouser['password'];
    return this.apiService.post(this.usersUrl, params).pipe(tap(
      (res: any) => {
        sc.dispatch(new GetAllUsers(form.role));
        this.store.dispatch(new GetUserDetails(form.username));
        this.notify.success('Success', `Created ${form.username}.`);
      }, (err: any) => {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.json().message === 'Invalid Credentials') {
          this.store.dispatch([new Unauthorized(), new Logout()]);
        }
        this.notify.error('Error', err.json().message);
      })
    );
  }
```

ApiService Post method:

```
  post(route: string, payload?: any): Observable<Response> {
    console.log("POST API SERVICE WAS CALLED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    let headers = new Headers;
    let data = {
      data: payload
    };
    this.setHeaders(headers);
    let reqOptions = new RequestOptions({
      body: data,
      headers: headers,
      url: `${this.url}${route}`
    });
    return this.http.post(this.url, reqOptions.body, reqOptions);
  }
```

I expected the Post to only occur once per call, but it SOMETIMES sends the Post request twice. Verified the Server on the backend SOMETIMES gets two requests. I've only noticed this occurring on Post.

Comment: Could you tell a bit about your backend too?

Comment: In a similar problem I had, Angular sends an option request with an empty body before sending the post request. You should tell your back-end to ignore it.